# Special re.sub python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to do some special re.sub
input

```
string = "\"hope\" and \"love\" or \"passion\" and (\"luck\" or \"money\") "
word_list = ['hope', 'love', 'passion', 'money', 'luck']
```

the hoped output is

```
'0 and 1 or 2 and (4 or 3)
```

i try with

```
print(re.sub("\"([^\"]*)\"", stri.index(r'\g<1>') , string))
```

but it dosen't work

Comment: Instead of escaping all, please use single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively (without `re`), you may iterate over the `word_list` using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and replace content of the `string` using `str.replace()` as:

```
my_string = "\"hope\" and \"love\" or \"passion\" and (\"luck\" or \"money\") "
word_list = ['hope', 'love', 'passion', 'money', 'luck']

for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    my_string = my_string.replace('"{}"'.format(word), str(i))
```

The final value hold by `my_string` will be:

```
'0 and 1 or 2 and (4 or 3) '
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub` function with *replacement* function as a second argument:

```
string = "\"hope\" and \"love\" or \"passion\" and (\"luck\" or \"money\") "
word_list = ['hope', 'love', 'passion', 'money', 'luck']

print(re.sub("\"([^\"]*)\"", lambda m:
    str(word_list.index(m.group(1))) if m.group(1) in word_list else m.group(1), string))
```

The output:

```
0 and 1 or 2 and (4 or 3)
```

(*keep in mind that there could be matches which are not in the `word_list` list*, e.g. `... (\"luck\" or \"money\") or \"compassion\"`)

> **re.sub**(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> ... 
>   If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering your word list, you can use `itertools.count` in order to count the number of matches and a function as the second argument of the `sub()` function that calls the `next` of the counter for each match.

```
In [10]: from itertools import count

In [11]: c = count()

In [12]: re.sub(r'"([^"]+)"', lambda x: str(next(c)), string)
Out[12]: '0 and 1 or 2 and (3 or 4) '
```

If you want the indices to be based on the word's indices in `word_list`  as an efficient approach you can create a dictionary from words as the key and indices as the values then use a simple indexing to get the corresponding index within `sub()` function:

```
In [29]: word_dict = {w: str(i) for i, w in enumerate(word_list)}

In [30]: re.sub(r'"([^"]+)"', lambda x: word_dict[x.group(1)], string)
Out[30]: '0 and 1 or 2 and (4 or 3) '
```

Note that you could use `list.index` method in order to access to word's index for each word. But due to the fact that the complexity of list indexing is O(n) it's not as efficient as using a dictionary indexing which is O(1).

Comment: It's wonderfull and it works, but i haven't understand what's the role of x.group(1)

Comment: @SlimaneMEHARZI It will give you the first captured group for each match which will be the matched string with the regex between capture group (`[^"]+`).